# Enum using in model first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Model

```
[Required]
[Display(Name ="Gender")]
public Gender Gender { get; set; }
public enum Gender
{
   Male,
   Female,
   Shemale
}
```

When I pass this into database it pass as a null value "0".
Controller

```
db.Employees.Add(Emp);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Database:

[image]

When I login form it through an exception

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The 'Gender' property on 'Employee' could not
>   be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a
>   non-null value of type 'CareersFYP.Models.Gender'."

Anybody can tell me how i solve this problem.

Comment: `0` is not a `null` value. Its the value for `Gender.Male`

Comment: make sure datatype in db or actual sending parameter type. in your case  datatype should be integer (not null)

Comment: yes it is male but when i select female it should be 1 but it is not change.

Comment: @StephenMuecke when i select female its value is not change. and when i wnat to log in any account it give me exception that i tell you.